# Facebook Application Tabs

Tags: facebook

I want to apply application tabs on my facebook application just like in following application:

http://www.facebook.com/artofnonconformity

I am unable to find any answer.

Please guide me on this

Thanks,

Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

If you're building an FBML app, you can simply use the [fb:tabs](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:tabs) and [fb:tab-item](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:tab-item) tags in your markup.

If you're building an Iframe app, you'll have to build tabs the normal way, using HTML markup and CSS.  There's lots of examples out there that you can google for that to get the exact stylings.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply, i have already used fb:tags but the look of it is completely different than the application which i have quoted earlier. I want the same look according to the 'artofnonconformity'application.